# What is listening on ports 2049, 34117 and 36105?

Tags: 18.04, netstat

```
fadedbee@ubuntu18:~$ sudo netstat -lntp
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:2049            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:34117           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2226/mysqld         
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:80            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2013/nginx: master  
tcp        0      0 192.168.122.1:53        0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3302/dnsmasq        
tcp        0      0 10.0.3.1:53             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2568/dnsmasq        
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1300/systemd-resolv 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1408/cupsd          
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2917/master         
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5434          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2145/postgres       
tcp6       0      0 :::2049                 :::*                    LISTEN      -                   
tcp6       0      0 :::36105                :::*                    LISTEN      -                   
tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN      1408/cupsd          
tcp6       0      0 ::1:25                  :::*                    LISTEN      2917/master
```

What is listening on ports 2049, 34117 and 36105?

How do I kill it without a pid?

Comment: Read `man lsof`, do `sudo lsof -i:2049,34117,36105` to see which processes have sockets open on those ports.

Comment: The open ports (2049, etc.) show up in netstat (without a pid or command) but lsof does not list them.